# error in cassandra-driver RequestHandler.getDecision on timeout

Tags: node.js, cassandra, datastax

uncaughtException: Cannot read property 'consistency' of null, TypeError: Cannot read property 'consistency' of null
    at RequestHandler.getDecision (/mnt/infibond/infi-version2/node_modules/cassandra-driver/lib/request-handler.js:351:69)
    at RequestHandler.handleError (/mnt/infibond/infi-version2/node_modules/cassandra-driver/lib/request-handler.js:304:27)
    at /mnt/infibond/infi-version2/node_modules/cassandra-driver/lib/request-handler.js:285:19
    at next (/mnt/infibond/infi-version2/node_modules/cassandra-driver/lib/utils.js:442:14)
    at EventEmitter. (/mnt/infibond/infi-version2/node_modules/cassandra-driver/lib/request-handler.js:281:7)

I'm getting this exception in specific cases when i have a timeout (from what i can see in the driver the this.request is null.)

did anyone fix this localy or knows what could have made this error happen?

thanks!

Comment: Please make sure you are using the latest version and if you can still reproduce this issue then please do report it https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/projects/NODEJS/issues. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The ticket you submitted looks like a driver bug: https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/NODEJS-296

It occurs when the Cassandra host is not responsive while preparing a query, which should not occur often as a query gets prepared once in the driver `Client` instance lifetime.

We've included it for the next patch release (v3.1.2).